# Abbreviations for hours and minutes in French?

Tags: indications-de-temps, abréviations

So in English, the abbreviations for hours and minutes is hrs and mins. Is it the same in French, or are such abbreviations simply not used?

Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual abbreviations for hours, minutes and seconds in French (*heures*, *minutes*, *secondes*) are the SI ones: `h`, `min` and `s`. These are also the abbreviations mandated by the [official Québec rules](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect1&info0=1.1.12). For minutes, `mn` is also commonly used, but less than it used to be. `m` is also common when used in combination with hours.

Putting an `s` at the end of an abbreviation to denote a plural can happen, but it's less common in French than in English.

People would probably understand the English abbreviations in context, but French people would not write `hr`. The official Québec rules explicitly recommend not to use `hres`, which is not something I've seen in France.

Thus a time interval of 2½ hours would typically be written “2 h 30 min” (spacing optional). When there are hours and minutes but no seconds, it's common to omit the unit for minutes: “2h30”.

For short intervals with minutes and seconds but no hours, you'll sometimes find something like 4’33” but this is frowned upon (’ and ” are symbols for arc minutes and arc seconds, not for units of time).

We often use this to write the time as well, but it's also common to use a colon between the hours and the minutes, e.g. 2.30pm is “14h30” or “14:30”. (Note that in France, the time of day is always written using a 24-hour clock since the beginning of the 20th century.)

Comment: Le lien c'est Termium i.e. le _Guide du rédacteur_, tout ça vient essentiellement du Qc. à l'origine... Voir aussi [_durée_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5099), [_heure_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1516) à la BDL. Merci !

Answer (score 4):

French follows the international standards and conventions and uses the official symbols<sup>1</sup> which are:

- a single ***h*** for hour
- ***min*** for the [minute](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_(temps)).

The only official SI time unit is the second. The minute and the hour are mentioned by the standard and their usage is accepted but they are not officially defined in the SI.

By typographic rules, an unbreakable space character is mandatory before all symbols<sup>2</sup> except `°`, `'`, and `"`.

**11:39PM** is ***23 h 39 min***, you might drop *min* here and use ***23 h 39***. If the context is clear, you might drop the *h* too and use a colon without surrounding spaces instead: ***23:39***.

Some people still use the [legacy](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jo_pdf.do?numJO=0&dateJO=19610520&pageDebut=04584&pageFin=&pageCourante=04589) convention ***mn*** instead of ***min*** but it has been obsoleted in 1975 when ***mn*** was replaced by ***min*** as the official symbol for *minute* and ***m*** curiously accepted as a shorter form ([see Journal officiel du 23 déc. 1975](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jo_pdf.do?id=JPDF2312197500013216&pageCourante=13222)). The ***m*** form that collided with ***mètre*** was abandoned in 2012.

It took around 30 years for the usage of ***min*** to overcome the technically illegal ***mn*** :

[image]

Note that very few abbreviations and no symbols at all do take the plural in French so ***mins*** is incorrect and ***hrs*** is twice more.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>They are mathematical symbols, independent of the language used, not abbreviations. As such they never have an ending dot like abbreviations built by truncation.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>To save space, this rule is sometimes broken and no space is used but it is nevertheless considered an error.</sub>

Comment: Je remarque que Facebook (fonctionnant en « Français (Canada) ») emploie *m* pour indiquer le temps qui s'est passé depuis la création d'un post, e.g. : « J’aime · Répondre · 32 m » Une faute peut-être ...

Comment: @LukeSawczak 32 m, c'est trente-deux mètres...  mais je ne vois que des *min* sur Facebook en français de France.

Comment: Il est peut-être temps que j'opte pour cette version alors ...

Answer (score 0):

We most of the time abbreviate it **h** (heures) and **mn** (minutes). But I assume we would understand **hrs** and **mins** with no ambiguity.

[Here](https://meltingmots.com/search.php?q=minute) is a nice website that I just found for abbreviations, if you have some more questions.

About the use of it, I would say it is quitte common to abbreviate these words, as for any frequently used measure (**s** for second, **km** for kilometer...).